# While reading multiple files into single data frame, create custom column for each of those files

Tags: r, file, csv, dataframe, plyr

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When importing CSV into R how to generate column with name of the CSV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5186570/when-importing-csv-into-r-how-to-generate-column-with-name-of-the-csv)

I got a collection of files that I want to load into a single data frame. Each of the files I'm reading has the same structure, but different number of rows. Let's say that each of those files represent a single participant, and I know I can read them using the code below:

```
files <- c("john.csv","fred.csv","nick.csv","alex.csv")
library(plyr)
dfoc <- ldply(files, read.csv, header = T)
```

Now, I want to be able to identify which rows belong to which participant. I want to add a single column for each of those files before I read them into a big data frame. The column I want to add will have a number of rows equal to number of rows for specific participant `nrow(john)`. The column I add should simply contain an identifier, for example file name repeated `nrow(x)` times.

Any suggestions?

Comment: @joran indeed you are right, I haven't found it and it's quite similar. Although there is no solution like the one pointed by Josh below...

Comment: Actually, the solutions at the post I linked to are nearly identical to the one Josh posted below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what I'd do. (The key idea is to place the value of the `id` column and the just-read-in data.frame together inside a call to `data.frame()`. R's recycling rules will make the `id` column have the right length in each case.)

```
## Set up a reproducible example
a <- tempfile()
b <- tempfile()
write.csv(head(mtcars, 2), file=a)
write.csv(tail(mtcars, 3), file=b)
fnames <- c(a,b)

## Here's the code you are looking for
do.call(rbind, lapply(fnames, function(X) {
    data.frame(id = basename(X), read.csv(X))})
)
#                 id             X  mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
# 1 file104862dd45aa     Mazda RX4 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
# 2 file104862dd45aa Mazda RX4 Wag 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
# 3  file1048d9e5764  Ferrari Dino 19.7   6  145 175 3.62 2.770 15.50  0  1    5    6
# 4  file1048d9e5764 Maserati Bora 15.0   8  301 335 3.54 3.570 14.60  0  1    5    8
# 5  file1048d9e5764    Volvo 142E 21.4   4  121 109 4.11 2.780 18.60  1  1    4    2
```

Comment: I think get your solution, but for some reason it gives 
me `Error in match.names(clabs, names(xi)): names do not match previous names` when I `do.call`. I think I need to revise the way I read my filenames, and it should work...

Comment: That sounds suspiciously like not all of the files being read in have the same column names. That's at least what I'd investigate first... Cheers.