# Merging only parts of csv file and add a coloumn with the csv file name

Tags: r, csv, merge

I wanted to merge cvs files stored in the work directory and its subfolder. 
This piece of code runs smoothly:

```
csv_files <- dir(pattern='.*[.]csv', recursive = T)
list.files()

my_data_frame <- do.call(rbind,lapply(csv_files,read.csv))`
```

So far so good. 
I now want to add a coloumn containing the names of these csv files. 
Furthermore, I want to extract only pieces of these cvs files, let's say from the  5th row to the 10th one.

Thanks for your precious help!

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46299777/add-filename-column-to-table-as-multiple-files-are-read-and-bound

Comment: not cvs - csv file

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5186570/when-importing-csv-into-r-how-to-generate-column-with-name-of-the-csv

Comment: I've already tried the solutions proposed in the possible duplicates. They easily do not fit with my specific issue.

Comment: If you're having a hard time understanding the solutions at those other questions, another option would be to use `dplyr::bind_rows()` instead of `rbind` and wrap `lapply()` in `setNames()` to created a named list instead. Pulling out the 5th-10th rows can be done by subsequently `dplyr::group_by()` and then `slice()`.

Comment: Would you please write down  the code which integrates all these suggestion? That would be very helpful! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply replace `read.csv` in the `lapply` call with your own function that does the subset and adds the new column. E.g.,

```
csv_files <- dir(pattern='.*[.]csv', recursive = T)
list.files()

#function to make df from each csv 
my_read_csv <- function(x) {
  dfx <- read.csv(x)[5:10,] #or any other subset
  dfx$fname <- basename(x) #add new column
  return(dfx)
}

my_data_frame <- do.call(rbind,lapply(csv_files,my_read_csv))
```

Comment: Function can be a one liner: `transform(read.csv(x)[5:10,], fname = basename(x))`.